# How to pass a function as props to a component of Material-UI for React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I wanted to make an **Appbar** which will contain a **SearchBar**. for this I was using **Material-UI** for **React**.

I have a file in my **component** section which loads the **Appbar**

Here is the `appbar.js`

```
function SearchAppBar(props) {
  const { classes, placeholder, writeInput } = props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="fixed">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            className={classes.menuButton}
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="Open drawer"
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography
            className={classes.title}
            variant="h6"
            color="inherit"
            noWrap
          >
            My Weather
          </Typography>
          <div className={classes.grow} />
          <div className={classes.search}>
            <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
              <SearchIcon />
            </div>
            <InputBase
              placeholder={placeholder}
              classes={{
                root: classes.inputRoot,
                input: classes.inputInput
              }}
              onChange={this.writeInput}
            />
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}

SearchAppBar.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  writeInput: PropTypes.func
};

export default withStyles(style_appbar)(SearchAppBar);
```

After that, I imported this file to another file named `searchbar.js`.

### Why I did that?

Well, so that I can control the input with the **component state** and the **props**

Here is the `searchcbar.js`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AppBar from "./appbar";

export default class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { term: "" };
    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  onInputChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AppBar
        placeholder="Search forecast for your favorite cities..."
        value={this.state.term}
        writeInput={this.onInputChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

And then I imported this file to my `app.js`.

Before diving deep, I wanted to see if everything works, so I put a `console log` but I am not getting any **console log**.

Rather I am having the error,

> Cannot read property 'writeInput' of undefined in appbar.js:46:29

`writeInput` is the function which I was sending to the Materila-UI's component as a props!

The link of the sandbox of the code is here, you can check the output too.[project's sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7j44l33v51)

**ps.** It maye take some time for the sandbox to boot up!

So, can I not send a function as props to the Material-UI's component? If not what's the alternate way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a function to functional component and access it. Don’t use this when calling writeInput. Since you are assigning const { writeInput} = props; you have to call writeInput or if you don’t assign like this then you can call props.writeInput

PFB corrected code

```
 <InputBase
          placeholder={placeholder}
          classes={{
            root: classes.inputRoot,
            input: classes.inputInput
          }}
          onChange={writeInput}
        />
```

Comment: What do you mean by **PFB**? And what's the reason not to use `this` here? Is this because `this` for `writeInput` is only accessible from `searchbar.js` and not from `appbar.js`?

Comment: PFB stands for please find below. Because you are assigning writeInput like const { writeInput} = props; if you don’t do this then you can call props.writeInput